# How can I create a regex that parses all lines of a string for a substring, and returns a match only if the substring is not found?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to build a regular expression but am finding it difficult to do so for this one particular case. I want to return a match only if the string I am trying to parse does not contain a specific substring. For example (searching for the substring "test" with case insensitivity):

```
"Line one
Line two
Line test three" - Return false.

"Line test one" - Return false.

"Tfest" - Return true.

"Tfest
Tdhf
Line three" - Return true.
```

I've been able to do this for single line strings using `^((?!message 1).)*$` but I'm not sure about multi-line strings.

PS: I don't want to start a debate on using string operations VS regular expressions. Performance is a concern. The constraint of the question is that the solution must use regular expressions.

Comment: `\btest\b` would work, if `IsMatch` then you can just run your code for it contains substring.

Comment: @abc123 It does not seem to work for @"Line onetddest (NEWLINE)
messadge 1dwd"

Comment: Try using the flag [`RegexOptions.SingleLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/443e8hc7(vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jerry, this worked! Post your answer as the solution.

Comment: "_Performance is a concern._" And you're under the impression regex is _fast_?

Comment: @GrantThomas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428776/why-are-c-sharp-compiled-regular-expressions-faster-than-equivalent-string-metho But again, I won't entertain this debate. Please use other threads to debate this clause.

Comment: Applying that link of a specific type problem doesn't necessarily generally apply; I'm in no mind to debate this, to be fair, it was an honest question. If you thought this specific to your case though, you might have added it to the question in the clause.

Comment: Instead of using: `if(IsMatch(Str,negativePattern)` logic, it would be much faster to use: `if(!IsMatch(Str,positivePattern)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the flag [`RegexOptions.SingleLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/443e8hc7%28vs.71%29.aspx) to make the dot you're using in your regex match newlines:

```
new Regex(@"^((?!message 1).)*$", RegexOptions.SingleLine | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dot doesn't match newlines.

As Jerry suggests it, you can use the singleline mode (or dotall mode) to allow the dot to match newlines.

An other way consists to avoid the dot, example for the word "test":

```
^(?>[^t]+|\Bt|t(?!est\b))*$
```

Note that this way is more performant since the lookahead is tested only when there is a "t" preceded by a word boundary. *( vs on each character with `^((?!\btest\b).)*$`)*

Comment: I like your search method a lot. This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for taking the time to add this useful information in!